# How to send parameter using ajax in datatable?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, post, datatable, send

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        let table = $('#datatableAttendanceLog').DataTable({
        "ajaxSource": "<?= site_url($url) ?>/datatable",
        "columnDefs": [{
            "targets": [0, 4],
            "orderable": false,
            className : 'text-center'
        }],
        "processing": false,
        });
</script>
```

This my code. I want send parameter to the controller(codeigniter) for filtering the data.

Code below, that using ajax{...}

```js
var table = $('#datatableAttendanceLog').DataTable({ 
        "processing": true, 
        "serverSide": true, 
        "order": [], 
        "ajax": {
            "url": "<?= site_url($url) ?>/datatable",
            "type": "POST"
        },
        "columnDefs": [
        { 
            "targets": [ 0 ], 
            "orderable": false, 
        },
        ],

    });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skvYJ.png)
And this is the data result in console

Comment: Use the [`ajax.data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data) option. This means you need to replace your `"ajaxSource": ...` option with `"ajax": { ... }`. See the examples in the linked page.

Comment: i try using ajax :{...}, but data can not display on table. when i try print in console, the data exist.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to show us exactly how you are using the `"ajax": { ... }` option, with the `"data"` and `"url"` options.

Comment: i hve edited my question. is it right?

Comment: In your previous version, your code did not specify a `type` - and therefore it was using `GET` not `POST`, by default. So try changing `POST` to `GET` (or just remove the `type` option completely). Also, your new `ajax` version is not using the `data` option - which was the point of the question, so you can send data from the web page to the controller.

Comment: in first version code, the data display on the table successfully, but I confused to send paramater to controller.  in second version, i know that i hve to use "data" option, but the problem is my data can not display on the table.